# calculating b from the Gutenberg-Richter distribution

Tags: r, probability, mathematical-statistics, exponential-distribution, geostatistics

I'm trying to calculate **b** from the Gutenberg-Richter distribution though, I'm struggling in understanding the calculation.

For example, the equation is this:

$Log_{10}N(M) = a-b(M-M_1); M \ge M_1$

$M_1$ is a lower threshold below which magnitudes are not considered. Parameter $a$ is the logarithm of the total number of earthquakes with magnitude $ M \ge M_1$, $b$ is a constant that relates the relative numbers of small to large magnitudes.

Then there's the Aki method:

Where b is calculated likeso:
$$b=\frac{log_{10}e}{\bar{M}-M_1}$$

Where $\bar{M}$ is the observed mean magnitude.

Given some sample data here:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   origintime time     magnitude
   <date>     <chr>        <dbl>
 1 2021-03-04 18:44:25       3.2
 2 2021-03-04 18:28:32       4.1
 3 2021-03-04 18:25:55       4.2
 4 2021-03-04 18:23:00       4  
 5 2021-03-04 18:20:00       3.9
 6 2021-03-04 18:15:58       3.9
 7 2021-03-04 18:11:41       4.8
 8 2021-03-04 18:10:57       3.1
 9 2021-03-04 18:10:33       5.6
10 2021-03-04 18:07:01       3.8
```

Please, I welcome any heartening comments towards understanding this as I'm having difficulties interpreting how to perform the calculations above with the following data.

I'm assuming the calculation for Aki's method is likeso, given the data above:

$b =\frac{log_{10}e}{\bar{4.06}-3.1}$

Though, I'm not certain about this, because given the natural logarithm is a constant, do I take it at the base $e$ ? Clarfication of my doubts are much appreciated.

Comment: It isn't clear what kind of help you are looking for.  You seem to ask three different questions: (1) "interpreting" calculations; (2) applying the first recipe; (3) applying the second recipe.  Which question are you trying to ask--or would it be none of these interpretations?

Comment: @whuber I do apologies for my brevity, hopefully I can clarify my expectations in this comment. Given the two equations, how would I use them relative to the sample dataset below, to derive the parameter **b** and $Log_{10}N(M)$? Presuming the Natural logarithm is a constant given in Aki's method. I provided two equations, as I presumed Aki's method is required to calculate *b* for Gutenbergs. Though, I presume rearranging Gutenbergs equation may also allow for this?